# Alternatives to point to GitLab private registry for Scala (Play) projects?

Tags: scala, gitlab, registry

1. What's the easiest way to publish ~10 public packages (like mockito-scala,java-jwt, ...) into the GitLab private registry? "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/SOME_PROJECT_ID/packages/maven"
   (mvn deploy:deploy-file?)
2. So the Scala Play project can point to the private registry?
   (Came across this https://github.com/gilcloud/sbt-gitlab. Are there other solutions?)

Comment: If the gitlab registry is a Maven/sbt registry, nothing fancy needed, just add it in the `/etc/SBT/repositories` file or in the project itself with `Resolver`.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to invest in a private repository that can act as a proxy to the internet though. Having to push public artifacts manually in a private registry is non sense IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish artifact to Gitlab private registry, the general command is:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
  -Durl=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/xxxxxx/-/packages/maven/ \
  -DrepositoryId=gitlab-maven \
  -Dfile=target/jar/ID-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  -DgroupId=ID \
  -DartifactId=ID \
  -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -DgeneratePom=true
```

And you can see an [`settings.xml/pom.xml` example here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/error-uploading-a-jar-file-to-projects-maven-repository-broken-pipe-write-failed/29168/4).
But only with [`maven:3.8.3-jdk-11`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/maven/library/maven/3.8.3-jdk-11-slim/images/sha256-655898a3416fda3bd5f6752ea27f2a7941e7d5176612953e803251522c04b5d3?context=explore) or more.